# Google "More" Menu Style In ASP.NET

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is there a way with ASP.NET, JS, or C# to make a dropdown menu like Google's "More" menu, which opens on click?

Comment: Yes I am Asking how can i do it Like Google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You havent shown which **`more`** you are talking about but i assume you are talking about following More menu:

[image]

Then what @Shane said suggested is sufficient, its just a drop down menu in an ordered list

```
<ol class="gbmcc">
<li class="gbmtc"><a onclick="gbar.qs(this);gbar.logger.il(1,{t:51});" class="gbmt" id="gb_51" href="http://translate.google.co.in/?hl=en&amp;tab=wT">Translate</a></li>
<li class="gbmtc"><a onclick="gbar.qs(this);gbar.logger.il(1,{t:10});" class="gbmt" id="gb_10" href="http://books.google.co.in/bkshp?hl=en&amp;tab=wp">Books</a></li>
...
...
<li class="gbmtc"><a onclick="gbar.logger.il(1,{t:66});" href="http://www.google.co.in/intl/en/options/" class="gbmt">Even more »</a></li>
</ol>
```

There's no Google magic happening there, infact using a jQuery [`Slide`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) function will look more cool.

Comment: Yes Exactly I Was Asking the Same Thing Which u show in Image But Where is class gbmcc and gbmtc ???

Comment: @AdeelAslam You can look for the class in the CSS files.. try using firebug to help you.. By the way, Here is the class for  gbmtc ".gbtc, .gbmc, .gbmcc {
    display: block;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}"

Answer (score 1):

It shouldn't be difficult. Try looking into jQuery's slideDown(), http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/, and slideUp(). Assuming you're not averse to it, and you're not that familiar with JavaScript libraries, that's probably the way to go. See http://www.mkyong.com/jquery/jquery-slideup-slidedown-and-slidetoggle-example/ for a demo.

Comment: This Method is Not like Google

Comment: Actually there are a few "more" menu options that Google provides. Google Search results have a "more" menu option that slides down. Put a better effort into writing an unambiguous question so that people can help you better.